# Filter by column using checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to be able to filter my table of data with the use of checkboxes.

[image]

```
@{
    var schools = CurrentPage.Children.OrderBy("kommun");
}
<dl class="dropdown">

                <dt>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="hida">Select</span>
                        <p class="multiSel"></p>
                    </a>
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    <div class="mutliSelect">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="Linköping" />Linköping
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="Norrköping" />Norrköping
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="Mjölby" />Mjölby
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </dd>
                <button>Filter</button>
            </dl>

            <div id="no-more-tables" class="sorttable">

                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width: 15%;" data-sort-initial="true">
                                Kommun
                            </th>
                            <th style="width: 20%;">
                                Skola
                            </th>
                            <th style="width: 15%;">
                                Datum
                            </th>
                            <th style="width: 15%;" data-sort-ignore="true">
                                Tid
                            </th>
                            <th style="width: 20%;" data-sort-ignore="true">
                                Adress
                            </th>
                            <th style="width: 15%;" data-sort-ignore="true">
                                Övrigt
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                        @foreach (var school in schools)
                        {
                            var times = school.Children.Where("date > DateTime.Now.Date").OrderBy("date");

                            foreach (var time in times)
                            {
                        <tr>
                            <td data-title="Kommun">
                                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(school.kommun))
                                        {
                                        @school.kommun
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        <text>&nbsp;</text>
                                        }
                            </td>
                            <td data-title="Skola">
                                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(school.Name))
                                        {
                                        @school.Name
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        <text>&nbsp;</text>
                                        }
                            </td>
                            <td data-title="Datum">
                                @if (time.date != null)
                                        {
                                        @time.date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        <text>&nbsp;</text>
                                        }
                            </td>
                            <td data-title="Tid">
                                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(time.time))
                                        {
                                        @time.time
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        <text>&nbsp;</text>
                                        }
                            </td>
                            <td data-title="Adress">
                                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(school.adress))
                                        {
                                        @school.adress
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        <text>&nbsp;</text>
                                        }
                            </td>
                            <td data-title="Övrigt">
                                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(school.oevrigt.ToString()))
                                {
                                    @school.oevrigt
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <text>&nbsp;</text>
                                }
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                            }
                        }

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Where do I go from here? I've never worked with filters before but I'm assuming I have to check the value from the filter with the table of data. I also know I need JavaScript too because I don't want the page to reload every time the user picks a filter.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: You could use Javascript to manipulate the dom and filter out the incorrect values. However (I might be wrong) using Ajax in my opinion would be better. You could use Ajax to send request to server with value of the checkbox and this value would be your value on your sql where statement.

Answer (score 0):

Using just javascript

```js
/* Demo filtering table using checkboxes. Filters against first td value */ /* Demo filtering table using checkboxes. Filters against first td value */

/* Set 'ready' handler' */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initFunc);

/* When document ready, set click handlers for the filter boxes */
function initFunc(event) {
  var filters = document.getElementsByName('tablefilter');
  for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
    filters[i].addEventListener('click', buildAndExecFilter);
  }
}

/*
 This function gets called when clicking on table filter checkboxes.
 It builds a list of selected values and then filters the table based on that
*/
function buildAndExecFilter() {
  var show = [];
  var filters = document.getElementsByName('tablefilter');
  for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
    if (filters[i].checked) {
      show.push(filters[i].value);
    }
  }
  execFilter(show); // Filter based on selected values
}

function execFilter(show) {
  /* For all rows of table, see if td 0 contains a selected value to filter */
  var rows = document.getElementById('tablebody').getElementsByTagName('tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var display = ""; // Default to display
    // If it is not found in the selected filter values, don't show it
    if (show.indexOf(rows[i].children[0].textContent) === -1) {
      display = "none";
    }
    // Update the display accordingly
    rows[i].style.display = display;
  }
}
```

```html
<input name='tablefilter' type='checkbox' value='1' id='tablefilter1' checked/>
<label for='tablefilter1'>1</label>
<input name='tablefilter' type='checkbox' value='2' id='tablefilter2' checked/>
<label for='tablefilter2'>2</label>
<input name='tablefilter' type='checkbox' value='3' id='tablefilter3' checked/>
<label for='tablefilter3'>3</label>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='tablebody'>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>First</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      <td>Third</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Very nice, but why can't it filter by string?

Comment: It is filtering by string, they just happen to be strings containing numbers in this example. Someone updated the initial [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lm7pytt/) I made to have [your Linköping, Norrköping, Mjölby strings](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lm7pytt/4/)